# How to redirect to parent window after logging in from iframe window?

Tags: javascript, iframe, redirect

I am using an Iframe window to display the login form of another website. And what I want is the user should go to that particular site after logging in(even if logging in fails, any click on any link in that iframe should take the user to that site in the full window(parent window).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the links (within the iFrame) are part of the other page, you can't "hijack" their `target`. You would have to have the means and ability to modify the `target` attribute of each link to point to `_parent` or use javascript to reference the `window.parent`.

Based on what you're saying (you're logging in to a different domain and the page is not part of your site) this wouldn't be possible without implementing some kind of proxy where you could modify the contents between page visits.

Comment: okay, Is it possible to somehow interlink the logging into the website and iframe?
That, if one logs into the iframe form, the user should redirect to that website?

Comment: @user: is this in reference to using some sort of OpenID implementation? what you're asking, as is, is like trying to include a google search in your page that submits the user's query to your site instead of `google.com/search` (which is a lot of hacking).

Comment: LOL, No
You are getting me wrong.. Actually bein more specific, I have a company website and another related e-learning website. Now what I want to do is-  Putting a login form of that e-learning website in the header of the company website, So that users can login directly from the main website to my learning website..
Is that more clear now??

Comment: The only bad thing I am doing is(I suppose) - Putting the login form into an Iframe!

Comment: I don't know enough about the learning website, but you may be able to just place a form directly on your site and make the action point to the learning website (as long as all parameters align) and specify a `target` on the form. This way you're still in control and not reliant on how the learning website's workflow operates.

Comment: That was the first thought I have When I decided to do so, But then I found that putting a straight forward login form is not possible for that particular leraning platform..
Any other solution ?
Or do you know someone else who can solve my problem?
Thank You!